# React-intl disable react-router's Link component onClick event on Safari v8.0.8

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router, react-intl

I'm working on a react universal application who is rendered server side and client side. The application works #1 on Chrome, but on Safari, the react-router's `Link` just re-render the whole application and do an http request.

The application render correctly, but the links don't do the transitions in Safari when it work perfectly in Chrome.

This is my routing.js file who is an expressjs middleware

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { trigger } from 'redial';
    import createMemoryHistory from 'history/lib/createMemoryHistory';
    import useQueries from 'history/lib/useQueries';
    import { match, RouterContext } from 'react-router';
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';

    import { thunkMiddleware } from './thunkMiddleware';
    import reducers from 'reducers';
    import routes from '../routes';

    const store = applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)(createStore)(reducers);
    const { dispatch } = store;

    function getRootComponent(renderProps) {
      const state = store.getState();

      const component = (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
        </Provider>
      );

      return {
        component,
        initialState: state,
      };
    }

    function routing(req, res) {
      const history = useQueries(createMemoryHistory)();
      const location = history.createLocation(req.url);

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        match({ routes, location }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
          // Get array of route components:
          const components = renderProps.routes.map(route => route.component);
          // Define locals to be provided to all fetcher functions:
          const locals = {
            path: renderProps.location.pathname,
            query: renderProps.location.query,
            params: renderProps.params,
            cookies: req.cookies,
            // Allow fetcher functions to dispatch Redux actions:
            dispatch,
          };

          if (typeof req.cookies.user_token === 'undefined' && (req.url !== '/login')) {
            res.status(301).redirect('/login');
          } else {
            if (redirectLocation) {
              reject(res.status(301).redirect(redirectLocation.pathname + redirectLocation.search));
            } else if (error) {
              reject(res.status(500).send(error.message));
            } else if (renderProps === null) {
              reject(res.status(404).send('Not found'));
            }

            // trigger l'action de "redial"
            trigger('fetch', components, locals)
              .then((cookieValues) => {
                let cookieTime = 3600000; // 1 heure

                if (typeof cookieValues !== 'undefined' && typeof cookieValues[0] !== 'undefined') {
                  if (typeof req.cookies.remember_me !== 'undefined') {
                    cookieTime = 1296000000; // 15 jours
                    res.cookie('remember_me', true, { maxAge: cookieTime, httpOnly: false });
                  }

                  res.cookie('user_loggedIn', cookieValues[0].user_loggedIn, { maxAge: cookieTime, httpOnly: false });
                  res.cookie('user_id', cookieValues[0].user_id, { maxAge: cookieTime, httpOnly: false });
                  res.cookie('user_token', cookieValues[0].user_token, { maxAge: cookieTime, httpOnly: false });
                }

                resolve(getRootComponent(renderProps));
              })
              .catch(reject);
          }
        });
      });
    }

    export default routing;
```

And this is my `app.js` for my client side rendering

```
history.listen(() => {
  // Match routes based on location object:
  match({ history, routes }, (routerError, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    console.log(routerError, redirectLocation, renderProps);
    // Check si renderProps est true sinon c'est un redirect
    if (renderProps) {
      // Get array of route components:
      const components = renderProps.routes.map(route => route.component);

      // Define locals to be provided to all lifecycle hooks:
      const locals = {
        path: renderProps.location.pathname,
        query: renderProps.location.query,
        params: renderProps.params,
        state: store.getState(),
        // Allow lifecycle hooks to dispatch Redux actions:
        dispatch,
      };

      // Fetch deferred, client-only data dependencies
      trigger('defer', components, locals)
        // Finally, trigger 'done' lifecycle hooks:
        .then(() => {
          const state = store.getState();

          // checkIfFormIsCompleted(location, state, () => {
          renderApplication();

          trigger('done', components, { ...locals, state });
          // });
        });
    }

    function renderApplication() {
      ReactDOM.render((
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Router history={history}>{routes}</Router>
        </Provider>
      ), document.getElementById(APP_DOM_CONTAINER));
    }
  });
});
```

When i `console.log` all in both, and all was ok. No errors, nothing wrong on the server and the client side. The links just don't want to trigger the history changes and do the application changes.

I use react-router-redux too if it matter and i just updated the packages just to check if they'll work, but nothing changes.

```
"react": "^15.1.0",
"react-router": "^2.7.0",
"react-router-redux": "^4.0.0",
"redux": "^3.0.6",
"redux-form": "^5.2.4",
```

I just digged into the DOM to see how click events are binds and i saw that links in Safari misses the event from `ReactEventListener.js`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASi1p.jpg

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you using an older version of Safari? The History API should be supported in 5+ https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/The-State-of-the-HTML5-History-API

Comment: I'm on Version 8.0.8 http://imgur.com/eCGNxGn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi had to add this polyfill script to my HTML page.

```
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Intl.~locale.fr,Intl.~locale.en" />
```

After, all works well! There was no console error or anything on my work's iMac, but on my laptop, an error was on the console.

You can see more infos here:

http://formatjs.io/github/#polyfills